# What href to set for routeProvider in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have page with `ng-view`. This page is generated by php following URL: `www.sbt.com/profile`

What url I need to set in `href` attribute, that will work Angular JS by url:
`www.sbt.com/profile/privacy/1`

**I tried:**

```
.when('/profile/:page/:type', {}
```

And link like as:

```
<a href="#profile/privacy/1">Go</a>
```

But it does reload page at url when I click to link in page `/profle`:

```
www.sbt.com/#/profile/personal/1
```

**Full code is:**

```
.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider

                .when('/profile/:page/:account', {
                    templateUrl: function(params) {
                        return '/public/html/personal.html';
                    },
                    controller: 'EditProfileController'
                })

                /* Chat */
                .when('/chat/dialog/:id', {
                    controller: 'ChatController'
                });
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your angular application is served from the page with base URL like `/profile` then links should look like:

```
<a href="#/privacy/1">Go</a>
```

and route configuration should be

```
.when('/:page/:account', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        return '/public/html/personal.html';
    },
    controller: 'EditProfileController'
});
```

Also make sure you define base href (although it should work without it too in your case). Put this script in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

Comment: When I am on page `/profile` and tried click link the page reloads on url: `www.srt.com/#/personal/1`

Comment: It means that link href is something like `/#/personal/1` I guess. It should be `#/personal/1`. Then page can't reload.

Comment: Does work Angular JS with href "/chat/test" without hash `#`?

Comment: Without hash it will reload the page because `/chat/test` is different resource. So you either use `#/chat/test` or you need to configure html5 mode, in this case server support is necessary too.

Comment: Thanks. Can you notice attention on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298550/why-does-not-reset-bind-unsafe-html-after-new-content please