# Why does not reset bind-unsafe-html after new content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AJAX request by click, that returns HTML content on page:

**Angular JS:**

```
request.success(function (data) {
   $scope.templateForm = data.html;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div bind-unsafe-html="templateForm"></div>
```

When I do next request `ng-model` does not updated. So I mean:

I get HTML from AJAX:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
```

In second request I get:

```
<div>Simple text</div>
```

But after submit form I get notification that must to fill input from first template HTML.

Comment: Read about `$scope.$apply`. You need to use it. It's the way you tell AngularJS that something in the `$scope` changed. `ngModel` does it internally for you, that's why `name` is set to what's in the `<input>` when you type, nothing magic happens. `input.on('keydown', function() { $scope.name = input.value; $scope.$apply(); }`. You need to do the same in your AJAX `success` callback.

Comment: This does not work for me